# MySQL Brackets?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, syntax

Latelly I've seen a lot of PHP/MySQL questions that enclose SQL values within `{}`, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '{$value}';
```

What's up with that? Is it even valid? Why do so many people use this weird (at least for me) syntax?

Comment: The {} is unnecessary in that example

Comment: it's not a bracket it's a brace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Complex (curly) syntax
>
> This isn't called complex because the
>   syntax is complex, but because it
>   allows for the use of complex
>   expressions.
>
> In fact, any value in the namespace
>   can be included in a string with this
>   syntax. Simply write the expression
>   the same way as it would appear
>   outside the string, and then wrap it
>   in { and }. Since { can not be
>   escaped, this syntax will only be
>   recognised when the $ immediately
>   follows the {. Use {\$ to get a
>   literal {$.

Answer (score 6):

Those are used to disambiguate variable names, and are absolutely required if you're using an array within a double quoted string, example:

```
$SQL = "Select * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '{$value[5]}'";
```

Wouldn't work without the braces.

Here's another great example from PHP.net

```
$beer = 'Heineken';
echo "$beer's taste is great"; // works; "'" is an invalid character for variable names
echo "He drank some $beers";   // won't work; 's' is a valid character for variable names but the variable is "$beer"
echo "He drank some ${beer}s"; // works
echo "He drank some {$beer}s"; // works
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php